# Qt visual studio building

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, qt

I have ms visual studio solution with qt project. When I working from visual studio all works fine. When I try to run *.exe file from building folder I see message that say Qt5Guid.dll(and other dll's) is not found.
What settings need to be changed that QT dll's moves to general building folder ?

Comment: Check out this article: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html

Comment: ***What settings need to be changed that QT dll's moves to general building folder ?*** You could just update your windows `PATH` environment variable to put the location of these dlls in the search path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find in Qt installation dir application `windeployqt`.

Run it like this:

`windeployqt  --debug  <path-to-app-binary>`

It will deploy all needed Qt files to your application's folder. You can read more about deploying here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html

Also you can try to add directory of Qt to `PATH` variable

*(Thanks king_nak and drescherjm)*